# LogStash: MongoDB input plugin to ElasticStash

Tags: mongodb, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-jdbc

Is there any plugin to input MongoDB using LogStash to store the data in ElasticSearch.

There is no search plugins available in elasticsearch website.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/input-plugins.html

Comment: Elasticsearch documentation recommends using this to clone data into es from mongodb: https://github.com/ozlerhakan/mongolastic

Comment: Thanks. Does it supports keep running as service and looking for any new record in MongoDB that needs to update Elastic Search. Like In LogStash using JDBC we can make keep running and looking for new record to be add to Elastic Search.

Comment: I have commented in this post my solution based on logstash-integration-jdbc https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54254754/logstash-mongodb-input-plugin-to-elasticstash/64522821#64522821